# Android Roboletric 3.0-rc2 RuntimeException and NoSuchMethod when running unit tests

Tags: android, junit, gradle

I just clone this project from Github: https://github.com/mutexkid/android-studio-robolectric-example

I m on Android Studio 1.2, Java 8, Ubuntu Linux distro.

When running the test with gradle it generates the message below. I got the same error on a Windows OS machine.

Any idea what could me missing ?!?

Thanks

Elcio A.

Executing tasks: [cleanTest, test]

Configuration on demand is an incubating feature.
:app:cleanTest UP-TO-DATE
:app:preBuild UP-TO-DATE
:app:preDebugBuild UP-TO-DATE
:app:checkDebugManifest
:app:prepareDebugDependencies
:app:compileDebugAidl UP-TO-DATE
:app:compileDebugRenderscript UP-TO-DATE
:app:generateDebugBuildConfig UP-TO-DATE
:app:generateDebugAssets UP-TO-DATE
:app:mergeDebugAssets UP-TO-DATE
:app:generateDebugResValues UP-TO-DATE
:app:generateDebugResources UP-TO-DATE
:app:mergeDebugResources UP-TO-DATE
:app:processDebugManifest UP-TO-DATE
:app:processDebugResources UP-TO-DATE
:app:generateDebugSources UP-TO-DATE
:app:compileDebugJava
:app:preCompileDebugUnitTestJava
:app:compileDebugUnitTestJava
:app:compileDebugUnitTestSources
:app:mockableAndroidJar
:app:assembleDebugUnitTest
:app:testDebug

com.example.joshskeen.myapplication.MyActivityTest > clickingClickMeButtonChangesHelloWorldText FAILED
    java.lang.RuntimeException
        Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException
            Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodException

com.example.joshskeen.myapplication.MyActivityTest > myActivityAppearsAsExpectedInitially FAILED
    java.lang.RuntimeException
        Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException
            Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodException

2 tests completed, 2 failed

:app:testDebug FAILED

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

- What went wrong:
  Execution failed for task ':app:testDebug'.

  > There were failing tests. See the report at: file:///home/elcio/AndroidStudioProjects/android-studio-robolectric-example/app/build/reports/tests/debug/index.html
- Try:
  Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.

BUILD FAILED

### Total time: 10.662 secs

Here is my build.grandle:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
android {
    compileSdkVersion 22
    buildToolsVersion "22.0.1"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.joshskeen.myapplication"
        minSdkVersion 16
        targetSdkVersion 22
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
    testCompile 'org.easytesting:fest:1.0.16'
    testCompile 'com.squareup:fest-android:1.0.8'
    testCompile('org.robolectric:robolectric:3.0-rc2') {
        exclude group: 'commons-logging', module: 'commons-logging'
        exclude group: 'org.apache.httpcomponents', module: 'httpclient'
    }
}
```

---

Here is my test Class:

```
package com.example.joshskeen.myapplication;

import org.junit.Before;
import org.junit.Test;
import org.junit.runner.RunWith;
import org.robolectric.Robolectric;
import org.robolectric.RobolectricGradleTestRunner;
import org.robolectric.annotation.Config;

import static org.fest.assertions.api.ANDROID.assertThat;

@RunWith(RobolectricGradleTestRunner.class)
@Config(constants = BuildConfig.class, emulateSdk = 21)
public class MyActivityTest {

    private MyActivity mActivity;

    @Before
    public void setup() {
        mActivity = Robolectric.buildActivity(MyActivity.class).create().get();
    }

    @Test
    public void myActivityAppearsAsExpectedInitially() {
        assertThat(mActivity.mClickMeButton).hasText("Click me!");
        assertThat(mActivity.mHelloWorldTextView).hasText("Hello world!");
    }

    @Test
    public void clickingClickMeButtonChangesHelloWorldText() {
        assertThat(mActivity.mHelloWorldTextView).hasText("Hello world!");
        mActivity.mClickMeButton.performClick();
        assertThat(mActivity.mHelloWorldTextView).hasText("HEY WORLD");
    }
}
```